# Use a defined trait as template parameter for another trait

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a **unit_converter** using traits. Here is what I set up so far

```
// create an enumerate class including basic distance units. 
enum class Unit {km, m, cm}

// name a trait _Measure_ holding unit and value
template<int v, Unit u> struct M{
    static const int value=v;
    static const Unit unit=u;
};

int main(int, char**){
    // ...
}
```

now, what I expected is write another trait `M_add` which can be called in `main()`

as like `M_add<M<10, Unit::cm>, M<10, Unit::m>>`, and it has the same inner parameters `value` and `unit`. However, in the process of defining such trait, I found difficulties in registering it with proper template arguments.

Firstly, I've tried using `M` as a 'type' so I can make operations on innter paras of a and b and assign inner paras of M_add.

```
template<M<int, Unit> a, M<int, Unit> b> struct M_add{

    // implementation

}
```

Then it returns `error: template argument for non-type template parameter must be an expression`

So I change the arguments as

```
template<template<int v, Unit u> class M1, template<int v, Unit u> class M2 > 
struct M_add{
    // implementation
};
```

while this time the registration pass the compilation, the implementation `M_add<M<5, Unit::cm>, M<6, Unit::km>> a;` in `main()` returns error `error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template`.

What I expect is to operate the inner parameters of `M a` and `M b` in template struct `M_add`, specifically the `a.value` and `a.unit`, so the typename specification would be necessary. So what would be the proper initiation for trait `M_add` in this case so I can do operation like

```
template<M a, M b> struct M_add{

    // implementation
    static const int value=a.value+b.value;

}
```

Comment: There's nothing in C++ that's called, plainly, a "trait". Just to be sure I haven't forgotten something, a search on cppreference finds nothing like that. C++ is very complicated, and it's very important to use consistent terminology in order to avoid misunderstandings. Can you [edit] your question and clarify exactly what you are asking, using the same terms that are used in your C++ textbook?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to write `M_add<M<5, Unit::cm>, M<6, Unit::km>> a;`, `M_add` must be something like this:

```
template <typename M1, typename M2> 
struct M_add;
```

because `M<5, Unit::cm>` and `M<6, Unit::km>` are types, not templates.

Your try with template template parameters would be used like `M_add<M, M> a;`, because `M` is a template.

If you want to only allow types instantiated from `M` to be used as parameters, you can add a trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_M : std::false_type {};

template <int v, Unit u>
struct is_M<M<v, u>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
static constexpr bool is_M_v = is_M<T>::value;

template <typename M1, typename M2> 
struct M_add {
    static_assert(is_M_v<M1> && is_M_v<M2>);
    static const int value = []{
        if constexpr (M1::unit == M2::unit) {
            return M1::value + M2::value;
        } else if constexpr (M1::unit == Unit::km && M2::unit == Unit::m
            || M1::unit == Unit::m && M2::unit == Unit::cm) {
            return M1::value * 1000 + M2::value;
        } else if constexpr (M1::unit == Unit::km && M2::unit == Unit::cm) {
            return M1::value * 1000000 + M2::value;
        } else if constexpr (M1::unit == Unit::m && M2::unit == Unit::km
            || M1::unit == Unit::cm && M2::unit == Unit::m) {
            return M1::value + M2::value * 1000;
        } else if constexpr (M1::unit == Unit::cm && M2::unit == Unit::km) {
            return M1::value + M2::value * 1000000;
        }
        return 0;
    }();
    static const Unit unit = []{
        if constexpr (M1::unit == Unit::cm || M2::unit == Unit::cm) {
            return Unit::cm;
        } else if constexpr (M1::unit == Unit::m || M2::unit == Unit::m) {
            return Unit::m;
        } else if constexpr (M1::unit == Unit::km || M2::unit == Unit::km) {
            return Unit::km;
        }
        return Unit{};
    }();
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jq1snbboo)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried your solution and it works in registration, yet what I expect here is to input two specific objects, saying a and b, in type of M so I can get access to their inner parameters `value` and `unit` to do addition. What should I register in this case?

Comment: @Chrsi Why would you want to do `a.value+b.value` when you can do `M1::value + M2::value`? `value` is a static member anyway, it doesn't matter if you access it from the class or from an object of that class. I added an example implementation.